# Can we interate socialite with backpack for laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack, laravel-socialite

We have the need to login user ONLY via OpenId (exactly Microsoft Azure AD OpenId Connect).

We understand how to use Socialite but we would like to integrate with Backpack For Laravel, because app is 90% base cruds and because we already have a paid licence.

How to integrate socialite with backpack for laravel?

- Also ... we should integrate it with laravel-permissions that it's very easy to integrate with backpack for laravel

Comment: did you follow the advice of @tabacitu? We have a similar situation

Comment: Time is passed and actually we have a working socialite OpenId Connect login and webpack. I cannot absolutely tell everythying we did 9 months ago. But it works. It's on a production server and does not create any problem. I can try to copy/paste relevant infos about what to do in a new answer if needed

Comment: Would appreciate any help that would save me some time. Thanks @realtebo

Comment: @petrivoges I added an answer with all what I'm able to remember. Of course, you must setup socialite and the plugin following the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a working solution

`config\backpack\base.php`

```
'guard' => null,
```

`.env`

```
AZURE_CLIENT_ID=0e8b592f-asaaaasd4eac-a368-d0d52dbc14e0
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET=b2r5442
AZURE_REDIRECT_URI=/sso/callback
```

`config\services.php`

```
// See https://socialiteproviders.com/Microsoft-Azure/#installation-basic-usage
'azure' => [
    'client_id' => env('AZURE_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('AZURE_REDIRECT_URI')
],
```

Packages installed:

```
"laravel/socialite": "^5.2",
"lcobucci/jwt": "^4.1",
"socialiteproviders/microsoft-azure": "^4.2",
```

`routes\web.php`

```
Route::get('/login', [\App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
Route::get('/sso/callback',  [\App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'ssoCallback']);
```

`app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php`

```
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Configuration;
....

public function login()
{
    return Socialite::driver('azure')->scopes(['openid'])->redirect();
}

public function logout(Request $request)
{

    Auth::logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    $request->session()->regenerateToken();

    return redirect("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout");
}

public function ssoCallback()
{
    try {
        $user = Socialite::driver('azure')->user();
    }
    catch (\Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException $e) {
        return redirect(route('login'));
    }
    catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
        return redirect(route('login'));
    }

    // Read the claims from token JWT using Lcobucci\JWT package
    $configuration = Configuration::forUnsecuredSigner();
    $token = $configuration->parser()->parse( $user->accessTokenResponseBody["id_token"] );
    $claims = $token->claims()

    // This is an example, it depends by your jwt 
    $full_name = $user->name;
    $email = $user->email;

    $app_user = User::firstOrCreate([
        'name' => $full_name,
        'email' => $email,
    ]);

    auth()->login($app_user);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will see what is usable.

Comment: Added .env and config\services.php

Answer (score 1):

If you need socialite, I recommend not using the Backpack authentication at all. Just disable everything related to authentication in your config/backpack/base.php file (the routes mainly), code your own controller logic with socialite and plug in your own auth middleware and guard within that same config file, so that Backpack uses your auth instead of the default one.

It will be easier to code and maintain your own logic, rather than mangling the default auth to work the way you want it.

Comment: we are happy to have socialite fully working with backpack (4.1) and without doing any bad things. 
backpackforlaravel is a excellent package, it worth every single $ spent for the licence!

Comment: Awww you made my day, glad to hear that 